# How to access yii2 url parametes in view page

Tags: yii2

This is my yii2 url

```
/stock-count/area-chart/stock-area-chart?AreaChart%5Bcompany_code%5D=001&AreaChart%5Bdivision_code%5D=03&AreaChart%5Blocation%5D=0201
```

I want to access 'company_code' from url  in view page

Comment: Try `Yii::$app->request->queryParams['AreaChart']['company_code']`

Comment: sir i want to access in javascript

Comment: add your js code. What you tried so far?

Comment: data: {areaCodeId : $(this).attr('id'),colourCode:color},  sir this is my ajax data mow i want to pass my company code like this above

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for parsing and getting data from URL Query string. [Refer this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

AreaChartController.php

```
$company_code = Yii::$app->request->get('AreaChart[company_code]', 'DEFAULT_VALUE');
return $this->render('view_file', ['company_code' => $company_code]);
```

view_file.php

```
<div class="company-code"><?= $company_code ?></div>
```